# SemaphoreSlim seems to get out of sync

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore

I'm using a SemaphoreSlim class to try to control the amount on concurrent db connections I have at time but where ever I have multiple threads going, n-1 threads complete successfully, but the last thread throws the Semaphore full exception. Which I understand the implication being that I have too many release calls compared wait calls, but I can't for the life of me figure out how this could be occurring in the sample code below

```
public static SemaphoreSlim Bouncer = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1)

public void WriteDB()
{
    int retry = 0;
    bool escape = false;
    while (retry < 5 && !escape)
    {
        try
        {
            Bouncer.Wait();
            using(SQLConnection con = new SQLConnection con)
            {

                /*Prep SQL command here*/

                con.Open();

                while (con.State != ConnectionState.Open && retry < 5)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    retry++;
                }
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                escape = true;                    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            retry++;
            Thread.Sleep(300);                
         }
         finally
         {
             Bouncer.Release();
         }
     }
     if (retry >= 5)
     {
         throw new Exception("Maximum Retries Exceeded");
     }
}
```

when I look at the log info the timings seem about right. it is always the last one out that fails. In my test trials, there aren't even any other errors getting logged, so I not sure how I am getting to the finally{} statement early.

Comment: There are only two scenarios that I can think of.  Either this code lives in a generic class so there is more than one static variable.  Or you are using Thread.Abort().  Don't abort threads.